# Ubuntu 18.04: Programmatic control of split windows

Tags: 18.04

In Ubuntu 18.04, is it possible to create the terminal to split up as say, 4 windows, and control the output that is going on each of them programmatically, depending on running a script or an executable?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Install and run `tmux`. Once in `tmux`, use commands like <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>b</kbd> <kbd>%</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>b</kbd> <kbd>"</kbd> to split the window horizontally and vertically respectively. Type <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>b</kbd> <kbd>?</kbd> to get tmux help.

You can start tmux from the command line and automatically create the splits.